# H1 and ul on the same line

Tags: html, css

Can you help me get some space between `<h1>` and `<ul>`?

```css
h1
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left:0;
    
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="" href="style.css">.
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Road to succes</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Stefan Dobrincu</h1>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="default.asp">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.asp">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.asp">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  <footer>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dobrincu.stefan">
  <img border="0" alt="Profile" src="Images\Facebook.png" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/stefanhab/?hl=en">
  <img border="0" alt="Profile" src="Images\Instagram.png" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
   <p> &copy; Dobrincu Stefan 2017</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the rule for `h1` from your CSS. Or do you want to put space between the right hand side of the `h1` and the `ul`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h1>` has already `margin` & dispaly `block` property why your are overriding that. Remove your `h1` css.

`h1` has default `margin-top: 0.67em;` `margin-bottom: 0.67em;` so it will automatically align. See the snippet output after removing `h1` css

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left:0;
    
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="" href="style.css">.
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Road to succes</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Stefan Dobrincu</h1>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="default.asp">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.asp">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.asp">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  <footer>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dobrincu.stefan">
  <img border="0" alt="Profile" src="Images\Facebook.png" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/stefanhab/?hl=en">
  <img border="0" alt="Profile" src="Images\Instagram.png" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
   <p> &copy; Dobrincu Stefan 2017</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want horizontal spacing use `padding-right` for `h1`.

```css
h1
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    padding-right:30px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left:0;
    
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="" href="style.css">.
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Road to succes</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Stefan Dobrincu</h1>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="default.asp">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.asp">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.asp">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  <footer>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dobrincu.stefan">
  <img border="0" alt="Profile" src="Images\Facebook.png" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/stefanhab/?hl=en">
  <img border="0" alt="Profile" src="Images\Instagram.png" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
   <p> &copy; Dobrincu Stefan 2017</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-bottom to your h1 class in the css file.

f.e.
margin-bottom: 10px;